# Query calling a stored procedure rollback transaction error

Tags: sql-server-2008

Executing a query (query is also calling a stored procedure) throws an error:

> The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.

However, executing the stored procedure in SQL Server produces no errors.

The stored procedure is rolling back after the end try:

```
begin
set nocount on;
    begin transaction
    begin try
      ....
      commit transaction;
    end try
    begin catch
        if (@@trancount  > 0) begin
            rollback
        end;
    end catch
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix exact error message

```
use tempdb
begin
set nocount on;
begin transaction
begin try
  create table foo1 (i int);
  commit transaction;
end try
begin catch
    if (@@trancount  > 0) begin
        select ERROR_NUMBER();
        select ERROR_MESSAGE();
        rollback
    end;
end catch
end;
```